# Reconstructed output mismatch for LTI system

Tags: fourier-transform, linear-systems, deconvolution

I have a system with measured input (`u`) and output (`y`).

I assume that this is an linear time-invariant (LTI) system and I want to find its impulse response (`ir`).

This is the Matlab code I use to find `ir`:

```
ir = real(ifft(fft(y)./fft(u)));
```

And this is how I reconstruct the system output:

```
Y = conv(ir, u);
```

However, as can be seen below, the reconstructed output differs greatly from the true output. What am I missing here?

The full matlab code including data can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/vL77E8pU)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the formula $$H(f) = \frac{Y(f)}{X(f)},$$ where $H(f)$ is the frequency response, and $X(f)$, $Y(f)$ are the input and output, is valid only for frquencies $f$ where $|X(f)| \neq 0$.

Furthermore, if $|X(f_0)| \approx 0$, you're going to run into numerical errors, since $|H(f_0)| \rightarrow \infty$.

Your input signal has **a bunch** of places where it's zero, or close to zero. I wrote a little function that takes care of those cases:

```
function h = impres(x,y)

X = fft(x);
Y = fft(y);

for i = 1:length(X)
    if abs(X(i)) > 10
        H(i) = Y(i)/X(i);
    else
        H(i) = 0;
    end
end

h = ifft(H);

end
```

While not perfect, and could be tweaked, I get:

[image]

where the red line is the estimated output.

One more thing to be aware of: the equivalent in time of the IDFT is the *circular* convolution, not the linear convolution. In this case there is not too much difference, but you want to be as correct as you can in your code.